# Double a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to double a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (no [DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)). Meaning I start with a stream and want to get a new stream where each element of the old stream is streamed twice. So 1,2,3,4,4,5 gives us 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5. Is there such a stream operation?

Comment: Just a note: another approach is to just create a view of the original collection (or other source of the stream) that returns each element twice. I'm not saying that's what you should do, just that it's an option and in certain cases the view approach works better.

Comment: @biziclop: this actually might be more performant than `flatMap` solution as the stream from such view will be able to report its exact size.

Comment: @TagirValeev And it doesn't require creating `n` intermediate streams.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create an inner stream which will contain current element two times and [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) this stream.

```
stream.flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e,e))
```

If you want to multiply the number of elements by `n` you can create an utility method like this one:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> multiplyElements(Stream<T> in, int n) {
    return in.flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> e));
    //  we can also use    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n) 
    //  but I am used to iterating from 0 to n (where n is excluded)
}
```

(but try to use a better name for this method, since the current one may be ambiguous)

Usage example:

```
multiplyElements(Stream.of(1,2), 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Comment: From a mathematically point of view a good name would be `diagonalize(Stream<T> stream,int length)` because the map A->A^n sending x to (x,...,x) is called diagonal embedding.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a stream of 2 elements for each original element and flatMap it:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5);
List<Integer> doubled = list.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, i)).collect(toList());
```

Comment: IMHO you should mention static imports, like `Collectors.toList`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example of what biziclop has described in the comments.

```
static <E> Collection<E> multiply(Collection<E> source, int count) {
    return new AbstractCollection<E>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return count * source.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<E>() {
                final Iterator<E> it = source.iterator();

                E next;
                int i = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return i < size();
                }
                @Override
                public E next() {
                    if (hasNext()) {
                        if ((i % count) == 0) {
                            next = it.next();
                        }
                        ++i;
                        return next;
                    } else {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

(Working example on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4lc5Wl).)

CW'd since it wasn't my idea and the `flatMap` suggestions more directly answer the question.

Comment: This might break some properties of the source collection's `stream()` implementation. It might be better to implement a custom `Spliterator` instead.